# jQuery plugin for text gradient

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, font-face

I have a text with embedded fonts which has to have a vertical gradient, can you offer a jQuery plugin for it? I need that the font family, size, and other attributes were preserved, and only vertical gradient was added.

I have found one ( http://www.codefocus.ca/goodies/gradienttext ) but it overrides all my fonts.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can

Simply call the css() method to again apply the fonts

Firstly, why are you not writing both code in one READY function?

Secondly, the solution (may be:) )

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){ // yup, I like to use it this way - safe

    var test1Opts = {
            colors: ['#FFF', '#EB9300'],
            style: 'vertical',
            shadow:             true,
            shadow_color:       '#000000',
            shadow_offset_x:    1,
            shadow_offset_x:    1,
            shadow_blur:        1
        },
        test2Opts = {
            colors: [
                '#FF0000',
                '#FF6600',
                '#CCFF00',
                '#00FF00',
                '#0066FF',
                '#FF00FF'
            ],
            style: 'horizontal'
        }

    $('#test1')
        .gradienttext(test1Opts)
        .css('font-family', 'YOUR CUSTOM FONT NAME')
    //  optionally you can call the following to apply font on all child items
    //  by uncommenting the 2 lines below
    //  .find('*')
    //  .css('font-family', 'YOUR CUSTOM FONT NAME');

    //  you can also use the short "font" syntax, 
    //  if you have a lot of options in your font-face

    $('#test2')
        .gradienttext(test2Opts)
    //  .css('font', 'style weight size/line-height YOUR CUSTOM FONT NAME')
        .css('font', 'normal bold 11px/16px YOUR CUSTOM FONT NAME')
        .find('*')
        .css('font-family', 'YOUR CUSTOM FONT NAME');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you just need to to give the text you want an id, and use this id in the jquery code. here a demo to do it:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.gradienttext-0.1.min.js"></script>
<style>
    p{ font-size: 30px; }
</style>

<script>

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#test1').gradienttext({
            colors: ['#FFF', '#EB9300'],
            style: 'vertical',
            shadow:             true,
            shadow_color:       '#000000',
            shadow_offset_x:    1,
            shadow_offset_x:    1,
            shadow_blur:        1
        });
    });

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#test2').gradienttext({
            colors: [
                '#FF0000',
                '#FF6600',
                '#CCFF00',
                '#00FF00',
                '#0066FF',
                '#FF00FF'
            ],
            style: 'horizontal'
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
        <p id="test1">test 1</p>
        <p id="test2">test 2</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does it preserve a custom font type which I have added via @font-face??

Comment: You definitely _don't_ need to give each element an ID. Just use any selector you want.

Comment: Karine of course it support the custom font type.
@powerbuoy how do we do that?

Comment: Well in the case of your code you could just say `$('p').textGradient();` If you want to be more specific you can say something like `$('#page-content p').textGradient()`. But you definitely do _not_ have to add IDs to every element you want a gradient on.

Comment: oh yeah i see what you did thanks, but the question is about different texts ;)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can do text gradients with pure CSS. The technique involves overlaying the text with a transparent, gradient PNG (you could use CSS3's `linear-gradient` as well).

You can read more here: http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css-gradient-text-effect

Instead of adding the `span`s required in the actual markup you could do that automatically with JS (or jQuery).

This effect will not change the font (@font-face linked or otherwise) at all.

Comment: It doesn't work for me as I have a background full of texture.

Answer (score -2):

you can just use css to do linear-gradient.

```
background-image: linear-gradient(bottom, #666666 23%, #908c8c 62%);
background-image: -webkit-gradient(
    linear,
    left bottom,
    left top,
    color-stop(0.23, #666666),
    color-stop(0.62, #908c8c)
);
```

Comment: But that would make the _background_ of the text a gradient, not the text itself - no?